# SocketException when using preferIPv6Addresses

Tags: java, http, httpurlconnection, ipv6

So I have a requirement where I need to access an URL while prefering `IPV6` if It's avail.

This is the piece of code I have.

```
private HttpURLConnection getConnection(URL url) throws IOException {
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(15 * 1000);
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.76");
    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    return conn;
}
```

And I am reading the connection output via a `Buffered Reader`.

```
HttpURLConnection conn = getConnection(new URL(API + urlParameters));
return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream())).readLine();
```

The problem happens on The BufferedReader raising the error

`net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect`

But when I remove this code block from my application, The program works as intended.
`System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv6Addresses", "true");`

But of course it sends `IPv4` IP Address even if the user can use `IPv6` How can I make it so it sends `IPv6` IP if the user cannot use `IPv6` It'll use `IPv4`, I am using cloudflare to logs the IP and by default cloudflare requires `IPv6` from the browser.

Comment: Test your network first: https://test-ipv6.com/

Answer (score 0):

Test the IPv6 support with this code before :

```
private static boolean supportsIPv6() throws SocketException {
    Enumeration<NetworkInterface> e = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
        Iterator<InterfaceAddress> e2 = e.nextElement().getInterfaceAddresses().iterator();
        while (e2.hasNext()) {
            final InetAddress ip = e2.next().getAddress();
            if (ip.isLoopbackAddress() || ip instanceof Inet4Address){
                continue;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```